# insert a character into a field based on If statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not very familiar with XSLT.

Basically, I have an array of items in my original XML, it looks like this:

**Sample input document**

```
<Items>
    <Items>Item1</Items>
    <Items>item2</Items>
    <Items>Item3</Items>
</Items>
```

**Expected output document from sample input**

```
<Items>
    <Items>
        <Item1>Y</Item1>Item1</Items>
    <Items>
        <Item1 />item2</Items>
    <Items>
        <Item1 />Item3</Items>
</Items>
```

How can I use XSLT to check each of the `Items` and insert a `Y` symbol inside a field in the modified XML or leave the field blank if such item is not found?

I have something like this right now, but I am not sure if that is a proper way of doing that

```
      <xsl:if test="Items='Item1'">
        <Item1>Y</Item1>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="Items!='Item1'">
        <Item1></Item1>
      </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Your goal is unclear.  Please edit your post to show the desired OUTPUT XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to use any explicit conditional XSLT instruction -- templates and templates patterns are your friends**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Items[not(*)]/text()[. = 'Item1']">Y</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Items[not(*)]/text()" priority="0"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Items>
    <Items>Item1</Items>
    <Items>item2</Items>
    <Items>Item3</Items>
</Items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Items>
   <Items>Y</Items>
   <Items/>
   <Items/>
</Items>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copie every node for which it is selected for execution "as-is".
2. There are two overriding templates -- one for a text node child of `Items`, whose value is "Item1" ("replacing"), the second -- for any other text-node children of `Items` -- "deleting" it due to its empty body.
3. The "deleting" template has its `priority` attribute set low (to zero) in order to explicitly resolve any priority conflict with the "replacing" template.